# XCode 14 canvas not using previewDevice as specified in the PreviewProvider

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode14

I'm currently following the [SwiftUI beginner tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation#Generate-Previews-Dynamically) of Apple Developers and I am having a problem with one step described in the tutorial.

The tutorial creates a `LandmarksList`, which content is not of importance to the question. In the `PreviewProvider`, several previews for different devices are created:

```swift
ForEach(["iPhone SE (2nd generation)", "iPhone XS Max"], id: \.self) { deviceName in
                    LandmarkList()
                        .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: deviceName))
                        .previewDisplayName(deviceName)
                }
```

However, XCode (I'm using version 14.3) always uses the iPhone 14 in the preview.

I know that I can change the device of the preview with the "iOS Simulators" setting in XCode, however, I would like to select the device as shown in the tutorial.

I'm following the official tutorial of Apple Developers, so it seems like I've missed something obvious here. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

I was following the same tutorial when I faced this issue.

I'm not entirely sure which steps can be omitted but I was able to get it working by doing the following:

1. Make sure iOS simulator for the target preview device is available.

   - [Check and see if the devices are listed under your iOS Simulators sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFtSg.png)
   - If not, click on "Manage Run Destinations...", "+" in the bottom left hand corner, select the correct device type, and hit "Create".
2. Clean build folder (might not be necessary) shift + cmd + k
3. Change "iPhone XS Max" to "iPhone Xs Max"

   - For me, "iPhone XS Max" is listed as "iPhone Xs Max" and it seems to be case sensitive.